# Excel VBA user form to display the sheet which is selected

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a userform which has a listbox (ListBox1)which list down the sheet names and I can double click on the list and it will take me to that sheet. I have a back button (CommandButton2) when I click on back button it will take me to the previous selected sheet.
I want to link my list box and back button so that when I click on back button the my listbox (ListBox1)should highlight the sheet where my back button (CommandButton2) has directed to.

Please find below my codes:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Sh As Worksheet

'for each loop the add visible sheets

For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

'add sheets to the listbox

Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sh.Name

Next Sh

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

'declare the variables

' modifed code for ListBox double-click event, store the sheet name before switching to the selected item

Dim i As Long

LastSelectedSht = ActiveSheet.Name ' <-- save the current active sheet before selecting a new one

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then

     Worksheets(ListBox1.List(i)).Activate

End If

Next i

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim TmpSht As String

TmpSht = ActiveSheet.Name ' <-- save the current active sheet

' select the previous sheet (stored in LastSelectedSht)

If LastSelectedSht = "" Then

    MsgBox "Error, no sheet stored , is it your first time running ? "

Else

    Sheets(LastSelectedSht).Select

End If

LastSelectedSht = TmpSht ' <-- use the temp variable to store the latest active sheet

' reset the userform

Unload Me

frmNavigation.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for al those loops to seek selected item, you can simplify things a bit as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Dim LastSelectedSht As String '<--| use as UserForm scoped variable to store the name of "last" sheet selected

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet

    With Me.ListBox1
        'for each loop the add visible sheets
        For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            .AddItem Sh.Name 'add sheets names to the listbox
        Next Sh
        LastSelectedSht = ActiveSheet.Name ' <-- store the currently active sheet name as the "last" one
        .Value = LastSelectedSht '<--| initialize listbox selection with the currently active sheet name
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' modifed code for ListBox double-click event, store the sheet name before switching to the selected item
    LastSelectedSht = ActiveSheet.Name
    Worksheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate '<--| activate the sheet whose name has been dblclicked
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Sheets(LastSelectedSht).Activate
    Me.ListBox1.Value = LastSelectedSht

    ' reset the userform

    Unload Me
    frmNavigation.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: @astha: the code above is all the code you need in userform code pane for the asked/shown functionalities. If you need help, just ask

Comment: This is the way I would have done it and is dynamic enough to deal with any sheets added.

Comment: thanks @Wowdude. Now let's wait for astha's feedback!

Answer (score 0):

This sub will change the selected item in the list box.

```
Private Sub SetListBox(Lbx As MSForms.ListBox, _
                       Itm As String)
    Dim i As Integer

    With Lbx
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            .Selected(i) = Not CBool(StrComp(.List(i), Itm))
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Call it from your procedure which activates the previous worksheet with a line of code like this one.

```
SetListBox ListBox1, TmpSht
```

Make sure that `TmpSht` holds the name of the newly activated sheet at the time you make the call or pass the name of that sheet instead of TmpSht.

Comment: Should I paste the Sub SetListBox in the module and in the blank button  (CommandButton2) type call SetListBox              Please guide as I am unable to understand